# Async REST endpoints with polymorphic return type

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

.NET 6, WebAPI, C#. So I want a REST endpoint with a polymorphic return type:

```
app.MapGet("/api/test", Boo);

//...
public static Base Boo()
{
    return new Derived(10, 20);
}

record Base (int a);
record Derived(int a, int b): Base(a);
```

Works as expected, returns `{"b": 20, "a": 10}`.

Now, if I make the method async:

```
public static async Task<Base> Boo()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return new Derived(10, 20);
}
```

The response JSON looks as if it's been cast to `Base`: `{"a": 10}`. Not the intended result. Any way around that (other than rewriting the whole method to a synchronous one)?

EDIT: one reasonably cheap way to make the whole thing sync without too much rewriting is splitting into two methods, one async, another explicitly polymorphic:

```
private static async Task<Base> BooAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return new Derived(10, 20);
}

public static Base Boo()
{
    return BooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: "Serialize properties of derived classes
Serialization of a polymorphic type hierarchy is not supported. For example, if a property is defined as an interface or an abstract class, only the properties defined on the interface or abstract class are serialized, even if the runtime type has additional properties. The exceptions to this behavior are explained in this section."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism

Comment: And yet sync methods with polymorphic return types are supported out of the box, no explicit setup necessary. The framework logic that does method execution (including awaiting) and result serialization *could* go by the runtime type of the await result, but instead it looks like it goes by the type `T` of the `Task<T>` specialization.

Comment: The problem solves itself if you pack you actions into controllers. This seems even much less messy than using app.MapGet. Would this be an option for you?

Comment: I only have a couple of methods where this is an issue. Having a mix of app.MapXXX() and controllers seems messy

Comment: As the document has shared which should resolve your issue, is there any specific reason you wanted to implement that using `minimal API`? if you wrap the all action within controller class then the `polymorphic` should implement as expected.

Comment: I have ~40 endpoints. Out of them, 2 are polymorphic and async. Refactoring all to controllers seems unwarranted. Refactoring just those two to controllers seems inelegant.